# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity error

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi im making a calculator on eclipse and im following this tutorial ive done everything exactly as in the video but for some reason im getting this "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity" error

```
public PlaceholderFragment() {

    int counter;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter += 1;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter -= 1;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Fragment` class does not have a `findViewById()` method; the `Activity` does, though. The compiler is complaining because this Fragment is a static inner class of an Activity, so it thinks you're trying to call that method.

If you are trying to get a view from the Fragment layout, then change `findViewById()` to `rootView.findViewById()`.

If you're trying to get a view from the Activity layout, then change it to `getActivity().findViewById()`.

(It depends on where the `bAdd` button actually is).

Comment: all 3 of them? @matiash

Comment: Yes. One more thing: `return rootView;` should be the last line in the method.

Comment: edit, now my counter is givng me an error..."unreachable code" @matiash

Comment: Check my previous comment about the return statement :)

Comment: @user3692770 I edited your code to fix that part (since this error was not actually related to the question). see where the `return rootView` is now.